# Как вытянуть текст с excel?

Tags: python, excel

Ребят как вытянуть текст с ексель чтобы внести ФИО в код а он тянул по нему всю строку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb['Sheet1']
rows={}
dates = [int(x.value) for x in ws1.iter_rows(min_col=2,max_row=1).send(None)]
for row,name in enumerate([x.value for x in ws1.iter_cols(max_col=1,min_row=2).send(None)],2):
rows[name]={}
for col,date in enumerate(dates,2):
rows[name][date] = ws1.cell(row,col).value
print(rows['Olena Kosr'][29])

print(list(rows['Olena Kosr'].values()))
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (можно выложить excel файл на любой свободный файлообменник) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: И проверьте, что у вас с отступами? Вы потеряли все форматирование кода - для python это критично. Как лучше всего форматировать код - посмотрите здесь: [Справка по Markdown. Код и предварительно отформатированный текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Настоятельно рекомендую использовать для python не отступы (из-за чего часто они теряются), а помечать код тремя и более обратными кавычками или тильдами